# Refactoring JavaScript (Swtich & Function)

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring

I'm a beginner at coding, and I'm studying JS. I'd like to know how to write a function inside a switch in this code below (if possible), turning the code smaller.

I tried to place the funtion for each operation inside of the switch, but it never worked.
Help me to improve my code. Thank you!

```
//Calculator of Basic Operations

function addition(a, b) {
  return (a + b);
}

function subtraction(a, b) {
  return (a - b);
}

function multiplication(a, b) {
  return (a * b);
}

function division(a, b) {
  return (a / b);
}

console.log('Choose the number for the operation you want to use.');
console.log('1 - Addition');
console.log('2 - Subtraction');
console.log('3 - Multiplication');
console.log('4 - Division');

let calcAB = prompt('Operation: ');

switch (calcAB) {

  case '1':
    a = Number(prompt('Enter the value for A: '));
    b = Number(prompt('Enter the value for B: '));
    console.log(`The addition result is "${addition(a, b)}"`);
    break;

  case '2':
    a = Number(prompt('Enter the value for A: '));
    b = Number(prompt('Enter the value for B: '));
    console.log(`The subtraction result is "${subtraction(a, b)}"`);
    break;

  case '3':
    a = Number(prompt('Enter the value for A: '));
    b = Number(prompt('Enter the value for B: '));
    console.log(`The multiplication result is "${multiplication(a, b)}"`);
    break;

  case '4':
    a = Number(prompt('Enter the value for A (dividend): '));
    b = Number(prompt('Enter the value for B (divisor): '));
    console.log(`The division result is "${division(a, b)}"`);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only things that change between the cases are

- The function called
- The name of the operation called
- The `(dividend)` `(divisor)` for `/`

I'd use an array for the functions and operator names instead - for example, `[0]` will refer to `(a, b) => a + b`, so that way you just have to subtract 1 from the number chosen by the user to get to the function. To get `a` and `b`, interpolate `(dividend)` `(divisor)` only if the case is 4 - but it can all be done at once.

```js
const fns = [
  [(a, b) => a + b, 'addition'],
  [(a, b) => a - b, 'subtraction'],
  [(a, b) => a * b, 'multiplication'],
  [(a, b) => a / b, 'division']
];
const op = prompt('Operation: ');
const item = fns[op - 1];
if (!item) {
  throw new Error('Invalid');
}
const a = Number(prompt(`Enter the value for A${op === '4' ? ' (dividend)' : ''}: `));
const b = Number(prompt(`Enter the value for b${op === '4' ? ' (divisor)' : ''}: `));
console.log(`The ${item[1]} result is ${item[0](a, b)}`);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll study all the modifications you made. I'm still a beginner and I'm still learning how to use an array properly. What you did will come in handy.

Answer (score -1):

Don't make your code complex in order to make it smaller, it makes it more confusing and misses the point, which is to make you understand the syntax and what you are doing

Comment: There is quite some duplication in the code that the OP *should* get rid of.

Comment: That's a  good point. I'll keep that in mind. My purpose here is to learn different ways of solving the same problem. Thank you.